# Jquery if statement help

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I want to know how to correctly write an if statement with jquery. I have a bunch of div's with an anchor in each that when clicked expands the the div's width using toggleClass. This works fine but I want to write an if statement that checks to see if the other div's have the same class applied, if so contract that div, then expand the next div (hope that makes sense), my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="content-block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content...</p>
    <a class="expand" href="#">Expand View</a>
</div>
<div class="content-block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content...</p>
    <a class="expand" href="#">Expand View</a>
</div>
<div class="content-block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content...</p>
    <a class="expand" href="#">Expand View</a>
</div>
<div class="content-block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content...</p>
    <a class="expand" href="#">Expand View</a>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.expand').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.content-block').toggleClass('wide');
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this, no need for an if in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.expand').click(function(){        
    $(this).parent('.content-block').toggleClass('wide')
           .siblings('.wide').removeClass('wide');
  });
});
```

This toggles the wide class on the parent, then removes the class from all it's siblings.

Answer (score 1):

No need for an if statement, just run `removeClass()` on anything that has the `wide` class applied to it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.expand').click(function(){
        $('.content-block.wide').removeClass('wide');
        $(this).parent('.content-block').addClass('wide');
    });
});
```

And for performance sake, just use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` instead of `toggleClass()`

Comment: This would not have the same behavior, currently his code collapses the current `wide` div when clicked, this removes that ability.

Comment: @Nick, I'm afraid I don't see what you are talking about. My code first finds the current `wide` div, removes the `wide` class from it. Then it adds the `wide` class to the now current `wide` div. Please let me know if I misunderstand.

Comment: If you clicked the current div and it had `.wide`, `toggleClass()` removes it...since you remove it from all then add, you're making the parent `.wide` every time, no possibility of collapsing it.  This isn't what the OP had, you're removing the collapse ability by taking this route.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write something like this:

```
var otherExpanded = $('.content-block.wide');
if (otherExpanded.length)
    //Do things
```